# How to authenticate AD users connecting from Power BI to on-premise SQL Server between different domains?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, powerbi

We are working on a prototype to connect from Power BI to a on-premise instance of SQL Server 2016 version. The issue we have is that Power BI and SQL server are in different domains and use different AD groups. We want to avoid implementing a SQL login approach because that approach would hinder us from implementing security based on AD accounts. Also, we wouldn't be able to implement security at Power BI level using inherent filters based on User Principal Name.

What's the recommended approach to connect from Power BI to SQL server across different domains?[image]

Comment: Is this Power BI the cloud service, or Power BI Report Server, the on-prem server, or Power BI Desktop?

Comment: Power BI Desktop, David.

Comment: We also have Power BI Pro and Premium licenses.

Comment: To connect to a SQL Server in an untrusted domain see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain

Comment: Thank you for the info, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft